# Can't parse twitter hidden input with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, twitter, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to retrieve count of tweets. And I found that actual number of user's tweet are in the hidden field.

[image]

Which, I'm parsing with BeautifulSoup:

```
def get_twitter(url):
  soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))
  for match in soup.find_all("input", type="hidden"):
    print match
```

result:
[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Px8a5.png)

And as you can see there's no hidden input field that you can find at screenshot from browser. Why it so?

Comment: Why aren't you using twitter API directly? Thanks.

Comment: Its probably added by JavaScript which doesn't render from a raw data connection via python or any other language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Used twitter API. Somehow thought that parsing will be easier. Thanks alecxe for advice.

```
import simplejson
from twython import Twython

def get_twitter():
    t = Twython(app_key='', 
    app_secret='',
    oauth_token='',
    oauth_token_secret='')

    user = t.lookup_user(screen_name = username)
    print "Tweets: " + str(user[0]['statuses_count'])
    print "Followers: " + str(user[0]['followers_count'])
    print "Likes: " + str(user[0]['favourites_count'])
```